# Mouseleave 'body' in Firefox and autocomplete

Tags: javascript

Mouseleave listening `body` and fires when mouse hover autocomplete fields (only in Firefox). How to fix it?

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(ev) {

 alert('out');

});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="email">
```